# Why is this set closed under addition? From Friedberg's Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question that I am struggling with:

[image]

Where $\mathcal{F}(S, F)$ is the set of all functions from the set $S$ to $F$. The textbook tells me to prove it and the unofficial solutions that I've found for this text state that it is, in fact, closed under addition, but I don't understand why.

If I supposed that $S = \{1, 2\}$ and that $f(s) = \begin{cases} 0 & s = 0 \\ 1 & s = 1 \end{cases}$ and 
$g(s) = \begin{cases} 1 & s = 0 \\ 0 & s = 1 \end{cases}$, then both of these functions satisfy  the property that $f(s) = 0$ for all but a finite number of points, and yet their sum is $(f + g) (s) = \begin{cases} 1 & s = 0 \\ 1 & s = 1 \end{cases}$, which is never $0$

Comment: still, it's not $0$ for only finitely many elements of $S$ in your example (which is vacuous because $S$ is finite)

Comment: Surely if $S$ has a finite number of points then **any** function satisfies the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the primary confusion here is with the statement "$f(s) = 0$ for all but a finite number of elements".

In other words, $f$ is an element of $\mathcal C(S,F)$ if the set $\{s \in S: f(s) \neq 0\}$ is finite. For your example, $h = f+g$ is such that $\{s \in S : f(s) \neq 0\} = S = \{1,2\}$, which is finite. Even though $f(s)$ is never zero, it is still true that $f(s)$ is zero "for all but finitely many elements of $S$."

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Supp}{Supp}$
The definition of $\mathcal C(S,F)$ can also be descrived as those functions $f\in\mathcal F(S, F)$ finite support, i.e.
$$\Supp  f=\bigl\{s\in S\mid f(s)\ne 0\bigr\}$$ is a finite set.

If $S$ is finite, this is automatically verified.

Another well-known example is the case the $S=\mathbf N$. The set $\mathcal C(\mathbf N,F)$ is usually denoted as $F^{(\mathbf N)}$, and is, in particular, the basis for the construction of the ring of polynomials $F[X]$ in one indeterminate over the field $F$.

This being said, the set is closed under addition because
$$\Supp(f+g)\subseteq(\Supp f)\cup(\Supp g)$$
and the union of two finite sets is finite.